# Cordova error installing android

Tags: android, cordova

I've read a lot of topics with this error but didn't help me.

I'm in the step:

```
cordova platform add android
```

And I have the error:

```
Creating android project...
"C:\Documents" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
   at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Documents and Settings\odedios\Datos de programa\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
   at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

It seems doesn't find some command ""C:\Documents" don't recognized.....

Then maybe the error is in the PATH, but I have the android platform-tools and the tools.

My path is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Archivos de programa\IBM\Personal Communications\;C:\Archivos de programa\IBM\Trace Facility\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\applications\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\odedios\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Python25\;C:\Archivos de programa\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Documents and Settings\odedios\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Archivos de programa\nodejs\;C:\Documents and Settings\odedios\Mis documentos\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried in another directory without spaces ? like "C:\Development"

Comment: @clem I've changed the project folder to another directory without spaces and it works! If you want create an answer and I'll check like a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're project path must not include any spaces.

You can use `C:\Development`

Hope it can help someone else !